# How to update phonegap push plugin?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm using phonegap push plugin

while taking build in phonegap the plugin is not supported.
Is there any alternatives for phonegap push notification..

Comment: are you using the latest plugin ?

Comment: I am using this <plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" spec="2.5.0" source="pgb" /> and this plugin worked till november 14 now it is not supported while taking build in phonegap.
I am getting error as "plugin not supported"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$cordovaPushV5](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotificationsV5/) is the latest version & works perfectly!

Comment: sorry for my delay thanks Muhammad $cordovaPushV5 it works perfectly